# no such column: blog_article.date

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Trying to add a DateTimeField in the admin panel for articles

```
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    no such column: blog_article.date
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Article

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('title', 'date')

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField("Text")
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Do you have pending migrations?

Comment: i don"t have pending migrations

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in Terminal:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

Alternative:
Exclude your migrations located in the folder /migrations/ and make migrations again.

Comment: Exclude my migrations,not helped,
during migration, writes
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()